# Reading and parsing files and it parameter in bash

Tags: bash, shell

For bash/shell scripting, I have a config file at */path/to/config.cfg*

```
[db]
hosts: localhost,foobar

[project]
port: 8000

[other_param]
debug: True

[logging]
filename: logger.log
```

I want to read this file and parse it and want to get that port. Basically,

```
project_port=get_port(config_file) # gives 8000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
project_port=$(exec awk '/^port:/ { print $2 }' /path/to/config.cfg)
```

Or:

```
project_port=$(exec sed -n '/^port:/s|.* ||p' /path/to/config.cfg)
project_port=$(exec sed -n 's|^port: ||p' /path/to/config.cfg)
```

Bash/*Sh:

```
while read __ project_port && [[ $__ != port: ]]; do :; done < /path/to/config.cfg
while read __ project_port && [ ! "$__" = port: ]; do :; done < /path/to/config.cfg
```

Comment: Beware: this wouldn't differentiate between `port` values in different sections.

Answer (score 4):

If you want **all of the configuration as separate variables**, you can do the following:

```
while read -r group_or_key value
do
    if [ -z "$value" ]
    then
        group="$(tr -d '[]' <<< "$group_or_key")"
    else
        key="$(tr -d ':' <<< "$group_or_key")"
        typeset "${group}_${key}=${value}"
    fi
done < /path/to/config.cfg
```

You then get variables like `$project_port` and `$db_hosts` for the entire configuration file.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a bash function that calls awk, like this:

```
get_conf() {
    awk -F':[[:space:]]*' -v sec="$1" -v key="$2" '$1=="["sec"]",/^$/{if($1~key)print $2}' "$3"
}
get_conf project port file
```

The range operator `$1=="["sec"]",/^$/` evaluates to true from the line containing the name of the section in square brackets until a blank line is encountered. While this is true, if the key is matched, the second column is printed.

Depending on your version of awk you may have more success using `-F: *`

Output:

```
8000
```

Comment: I've tried this and it seems to work (mostly; it will match `port` in a section named `[fooproject]`, for example), but I don't quite see how. It looks like `$1` on the same line is compared to both the project and the key.

Comment: I've changed it to do a literal match for the section name and added some explanation. Perhaps you missed the range operator?